# Google cloud cron.yaml schedule formatting for custom repetitive interval

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, cron

I'm struggling to format a cron schedule for gcp properly and the docs aren't really helping me out.

Cron #1: Run every 50 minutes from 11:00 to 21:00 only on the months from march to october inclusive

```
  schedule: every 50 minutes from 11:00 to 21:00 of mar,apr,may,jun,jul,aug,sep,oct
```

Cron #2: Run every day at 22:00 only on the months from march to october inclusive

```
  schedule: every day 22:00 of mar,apr,may,jun,jul,aug,sep,oct
```

Neither of those work, but they were one of my attempts.  What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referring to the [Formatting the schedule](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/cronref#formatting_the_schedule) docs below.

There is no supported syntax for your 1st cron:

- specifying minutes in an `[INTERVAL_VALUE]` is only supported by [END-TIME INTERVAL](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/cronref#end-time) and [START-TIME INTERVAL](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/cronref#start-time) formats, but neither of them allows specifying months in the `[INTERVAL_SCOPE]`.
- the only format supporting month specification in `[INTERVAL_SCOPE]` is [CUSTOM INTERVAL](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/cronref#custom), but that only supports day specifications in `[INTERVAL_VALUE]`.

But you can achieve an equivalent functionality by using the finer time specification in `cron.yaml` and making a check for the remaining conditions inside the cron job itself, doing nothing if the condition is not met. So your 1st cron would be achieved with:

- this `cron.yaml` entry:

  ```
  schedule: every 50 minutes from 11:00 to 21:00
  ```
- an additional check for the current month inside the cron job itself, doing nothing (just returning) if the month is Jan, Feb, Nov or Dec.

Your 2nd cron is possible using a [CUSTOM INTERVAL](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/cronref#custom), you just need to place the hour at the end of the `[INTERVAL_SCOPE]`. From the doc:

> [INTERVAL_SCOPE]: Specifies a clause that corresponds with the
>   specified [INTERVAL_VALUE]. Custom intervals can include the `of
>   [MONTH]` clause, which specifies a single month in a year, or a
>   comma-separated list of multiple months. You must also define a
>   specific time for when you want the job to run, for example: `of
>   [MONTH] [HH:MM]`.

So your entry would be:

```
schedule: every day of mar,apr,may,jun,jul,aug,sep,oct 22:00
```